# import module for side-effects with Typescript only targeting node

Tags: node.js, typescript, module

## GIVEN:

A ts module with an `import` but no `export` calls named **./snippets.ts**
A ts module called **./main.ts**
A **tsconfig** as follows...

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "allowJs": true,                       
    "checkJs": true,                       
    "sourceMap": true,                     
    "downlevelIteration": true,            
    "noImplicitAny": true,                 
    "moduleResolution": "node",            
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  
    "esModuleInterop": true,                   
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

## Question:

How do I import the **./snippets** file in the **./main** module so as I can be assured that **./snippets** has run before **./main**?

I have tried `import from "./snippet";` and `import * as arbitrarySymbol from "./snippet";` and variations with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import "./snippet";
```

should do the trick as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only)